# SharePoint 2010 - How to get document ID using SPServices SQL search query?

Tags: caml-query, spservices, ajax, query, document-id

Using SPServices to make search requests, I am building the query like this:

```
var queryText;
queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>";
queryText += "<Query>";
queryText += "<Context>";
queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>";
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path, Filename FROM Scope() WHERE CONTAINS ('" + text + "') AND ((\"SCOPE\" = '" + scope + "')) ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC";
queryText += "</QueryText>";
queryText += "</Context>";
queryText += "<Range><Count>1000</Count></Range>";
queryText += "</Query>";
queryText += "</QueryPacket>";
```

How can I include the property which gives me the document ID?

Answer (score 0):

Change the querytext to:

```
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path, Filename, spdocid FROM Scope() WHERE CONTAINS ('" + text + "') AND ((\"SCOPE\" = '" + scope + "')) ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC";
```

Comment: I got this `<ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response"><Response domain=""><Status>ERROR_SERVER</Status><DebugErrorMessage>Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.InvalidPropertyException</DebugErrorMessage></Response></ResponsePacket>` when adding `spdocid`.

Comment: Please check if there is a Managed Property with that name in your environment.